# radio group, calculating answers twice

Tags: android, android-radiogroup

My issue must have a simple answer and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious... Could anyone point it out for me?

When I run the app on my phone the radio group behaves properly (meaning the score is 0 for the incorrect answer and 1 for the correct answer) however if I click the incorrect answer, then **back** to the correct answer and resubmit, it adds one more to the score. So the same question would show two points just for clicking the correct answer twice...

```
package com.example.android.englishquizl3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.example.android.englishquizl3.R.id.radioButton2;
import static com.example.android.englishquizl3.R.id.radioButton3;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int baseScore = 0;
private RadioGroup radioGroup1;
private RadioGroup radioGroup2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialize Radio Group and attach click handler
    radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
    radioGroup1.clearCheck();
    radioGroup2.clearCheck();

    // Attaches checkedChangeListener to radio group
    radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton your = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioButton2);

            if (your.isChecked()) {
                baseScore = baseScore + 1;
            } else {
            }

            int score = 1;
            if (your.isChecked()) score += 1;

            switch (score) {
                case R.id.radioButton2:
                    if (your.isChecked()) ;
                    score++;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

    radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton theyre = (RadioButton) findViewById(radioButton3);

            if (theyre.isChecked()) {
                baseScore = baseScore + 1;
            } else {
            }

            int score = 1;
            if (theyre.isChecked()) score += 1;

            switch (score) {
                case R.id.radioButton3:
                    if (theyre.isChecked()) ;
                    score++;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });

}

public void onSubmit(View v) {
    RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) radioGroup1.findViewById(radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) radioGroup2.findViewById(radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Score: " + baseScore, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

And my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="1) I think _______ cat is lovely."
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="you're" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="your" />
</RadioGroup>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="2) _______ going to shop tomorrow."
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="They're" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Their" />
</RadioGroup>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onSubmit"
        android:text="Submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think the main problem is your code contains too many unnecessary if statements and an unnecessary switch statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are only adding 1 to the `baseScore` so each time you change the state and have the correct answer you add one more. You would have to reduce the baseScore if you check the wrong number or just set it to 1

Answer (score 0):

@Emily your question has a lot of errors in the switch case you have added semicolon to the if condition which i don't know why because there is no sense in having an if statement like that in this case.

And on checked changed you are adding to a variable which already has score 1.

My suggestion would be you better have took a global variable to keep track of score.